# JavaFX - move columns in tableview

Tags: java, javafx, save, tableview

In (JavaFX) a tableview, you can automatically move columns(change the order of the columns).
But this will not store in the List.

So how can I save it, or is there any better way to move columns and save it in the DataList?

Answer (score 1):

> But this will not store in the List.

No, the tablecolumn order will be stored in `tableView.getColumns()` observable list. Please refer to javadoc. By traversing this list you can persist the `id`s of tablecolumns, and restore them on next app start. Or you may develop other ways of persisting the tablecolumn order.